# IFELSE condition is showing wrong values in R

Tags: r, if-statement, lubridate

```
if (!require("librarian"))install.packages("librarian")
librarian::shelf(stringr,stringi,dplyr,lubridate)


Birth_Date <- c("1965-02-06","",NA,"1995-03-04","","1996-02-05")
Party_Date <- c("1969-02-06","2000-05-09","",NA,"2001-01-01","1996-02-05")


Data_DF <- data.frame(Party_Date,Birth_Date)

Data_DF$Party_Date <- as_date(Data_DF$Party_Date)
Data_DF$Birth_Date <- as_date(Data_DF$Birth_Date)


Data_DF$Birth_Date <- ifelse( (is.na(Data_DF$Birth_Date) | Data_DF$Birth_Date =="") &
                       !(is.na(Data_DF$Party_Date)) ,
                         Data_DF$Party_Date,
                         Data_DF$Birth_Date
                        )


Data_DF$Party_Date <- as_date(Data_DF$Party_Date)
Data_DF$Birth_Date <- as_date(Data_DF$Birth_Date)
```

Expected Output:

```
Party_date    Birth_date
1969-02-06    1965-02-06
2000-05-09    2000-05-09
NA            NA
NA            1995-03-04
2001-01-01    2001-01-01
1996-02-05    1996-02-05
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set `Data_DF$Birth_Date` as a Date (not string) object, and then you compare it to a string `Data_DF$Birth_Date ==""` and that results in NAs because they're different types.

Then, per the help in `ifelse`

> The mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to accommodate
> first any values taken from yes and then any values taken from no.

In this case that converts your dates to numeric. Perhaps you want something like this to produce the desired output:

```
Data_DF$Birth_Date2 <- dplyr::if_else(is.na(Data_DF$Birth_Date) &
                                     !is.na(Data_DF$Party_Date),
                                     Data_DF$Party_Date,
                                     Data_DF$Birth_Date)
```